# how to shift fill function 0.5 forward in pinescript?

Tags: pine-script

I want to fill the area from just left of candle body, but the code I have written draw fill like that...so I want to the area filled shifted right 0.5.

[image]

```
inFiveLH = ta.sma(low, 5) < ta.sma(close, 3) and ta.sma(close, 3) < ta.sma(high, 5) and ta.sma(low, 5) < ta.sma(close, 2) and ta.sma(close, 2) < ta.sma(high, 5) and ta.sma(low, 5) < ta.sma(close, 1) and ta.sma(close, 1) < ta.sma(high, 5)
plot(ta.sma(close,200), color = color.blue, linewidth= 3)
plot(ta.sma(high,5), color= inFiveLH?color.white: color.purple, linewidth = 1, style = plot.style_circles)
plot(ta.sma(low,5), color= inFiveLH?color.white: color.purple, linewidth = 1, style = plot.style_circles)
plot(ta.sma(close,50), color= color.blue, linewidth = 2)
plot(ta.sma(close,3), color=color.red, linewidth= 1)
plot(ta.sma(close,2), color= color.green, linewidth= 1)
plot(ta.sma(close,1), color= color.rgb(255, 247, 0), linewidth= 1)
plot(ta.vwap(close), color = color.white)
sma5H = plot(ta.sma(high,5))
sma5L = plot(ta.sma(low,5))
fill(sma5H,sma5L, color= inFiveLH?color.rgb(255, 255, 255, 79):color.rgb(0, 187, 212, 97) )
```

Comment: Please edit your question and format the code part accordingly.

Comment: Fill the background is in the vertical line of the wick. Does not fill the sides of the sail body